# How to decrease computational time of extended Cox model for (start, stop) style survival data

Tags: r, survival-analysis, cox-regression

I have set up an extended Cox model in R which contains one time-dependent covariate X1 (X2-X7 are time-independet)
`coxph(Surv(start, stop, status) ~ X1 + X2 + ... + X7, data = data).`

To include this time-dependent variable into the model, I created the data-set in a "(start, stop) style" which extends the originally around 1500 observations to about 2500 rows.

```
   subjid  start   stop  status  X1    X2     X3    X4       X5     X6   X7
       1  0.000000 15.572895      1  0     Y      Y     Y        Y      1    10
       2  0.000000  4.501027      1  0     Y      Y     Y        Y      1    15
       3  0.000000 13.930185      0  0     Y      Y     N        N      1    30
       3 13.930185 17.117043      0  1     Y      Y     N        N      1    12
       3 17.117043 34.036961      0  0     Y      Y     N        N      1    7
       4  0.000000 26.381930      1  0     Y      Y     Y        Y      0    3
       5  0.000000  5.880903      0  0     Y      N     N        N      1    22
       5  5.880903  9.067762      0  1     Y      N     N        N      1    1   
       5  9.067762 12.188912      1  0     Y      N     N        N      1    11 
       6  0.000000 16.164271      1  0     Y      N     N        Y      1    12
```

For up to 1300 observations, the code executes properly (even though it takes quite long if I include more than 1000). Including more observations causes a non-responding software R (I was waiting for about 5 hours for the program to give me the results but it stayed frozen). 
This is consistent with the statement on the R coxph help website under "ties" (http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/survival/html/coxph.html). However, I cannot reduce my sample size (i.e. my data set) and thus I am looking for other suggestions how I could make this code running (faster).

Thanks,
Elly

Comment: Perhaps the only solution would be to try fitting the model on a much more powerful computer with lots of ram and running 64 bit R. What are the specs of the pc that took 5 hours?

Comment: @Shekeine: It is an Intel Core i5-2520M CPU 2.50GHz and 4 GB RAM. 32-bit Operating System. The sad thing is that even after 5 hours it was not done. I just quit the program.

Comment: Define factors as `cluster` if applicable. This vastly improved calculation time for me.